# In need of a way to ping a specific IP address and record the time of each ping aswell as the result

Tags: python, networking, scripting

Basically I need a way to check my internet connectivity in a sense. I've been having trouble with my net dropping out randomly and know it's not my end. But the ISP wants a little more proof. Basically I need something that can check latency and if its connecting at all on roughly an hourly basis and recording this information to a text file that I can view (and read back to them when I call them up next.) I was originally thinking of using python but my python is dodgy at best. But if another way is easier (either using a different scripting language or some program) I'm happy to use that as well.

EDIT: I'm not sure if that was clear so I'll summarize. It needs to ping, then record the response and the time it was pinged in a text document in a readable way. It must ping roughly every hour.

Comment: Could you please leave example with your suggestions? Just makes it easier for me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could just redirect constant ping results to a txt file. from command prompt (as admin)  ping (address) -t >log.txt

Comment: It needs to be readable, it would be difficult to find when the pings failed with that would it not?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean associate time with the pings - you could write it as a batch file where you called the time (with a /T so it doesn't ask for input) and does a ping (don't add the -t there so it runs just the standard 4) and then loops.  Or you could consider running a tracert (in a loop) which would give a longer but more meaningful output as to whether the failure might be happening (Maybe you're getting out past your router but not getitng DNS, that type of thing).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below calling it with a redirect to a log file (temp.bat > fred.log) 
 - using timeout /t to give you a wait of however many seconds you'd like 
 - and changing the IP address to a name address to check dns
 - and you could use ping instead of tracert
 - to kill it (since you won't see it on screen) you'd need to do the ^C and then Y -  since it's asking if you want to end the script. 
 Be sure to check your target address responds properly of course.

```
@echo off
cls
:start
time /t
tracert 192.168.1.1
timeout /t 10
goto start
```